# using ClientScriptIncludeRegister to get a hidden field value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am implementing a web application using ASP.NET/VB. The front-end (.aspx) executes an external `.js` file as:

`<script type =" text/javascript" src="External.js"></script>`

where it contains some functions. One of these functions called `populateHidden()` is used to assign a value to the `hiddenField` I defined on the front-end (.aspx) as follows:

**In External.js**

`document.getElementByID('Hidden2').value = "dsadsadas";`

**In .aspx**

`<input id="Hidden2" type ="hidden" runat="server" />`

what I have been trying to do is to get the value assigned to `Hidden2` and pass it to the server-side (.aspx.vb) using:

`Dim str = Hidden2.value`

However, since server-side code executes first,`str` would be empty and unless a `postback` is done somehow whether using a `Button` or a `Timer` to reload the front-end, then `str` will have `dsadsadas`. I do not intend to reload the page or initialize a `postback`. I tried `window.onload = populateHidden()` with no luck. This situation made me desperate since I tried to many things making sure I do not use `postbacks or reloads` until I came across [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx145dw2.aspx) . I couldn't not get around onto how I can use such an example to solve my situation.

1. The idea in mind is to call or execute `External.js` from the server side (since it executes first), then populate `Hidden2` on the front-end, go back to the server side and retrieve `Hidden2.value`.
2. However the example in the link mentioned earlier, the server-side code is written in the front-end but I want to write it on the server-side (.aspx.vb).
3. The reason why I need `Hidden2.value` in the server-side is to store it in my `sql_database`. Any suggestions, advice or solutions to get `Hidden2.value` from the front-end would be really appreciated.

Comment: You either need to postback the form or submit the data via ajax. [Implementing Client Callbacks Without Postbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx)

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Well what I would require is the exact opposite, to run client-code on server side with no postback.

Comment: What you require is AJAX if you don't want postback. You can't run client-code on the server.... since you are on the server. You can asynchronously post the client data to the server without causing a full page postback.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev could you provide me with a similar example? And if I userd `ASP.NET` controls, will they work on any browser if the whole project was uploaded on a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses only ASP.Net Ajax Engine. In PageLoad event, a call to `populateHidden()` function is being registered. In the codebehind, a method marked with the `WebMethod` attribute was added, allowing it to be called by an Ajax request (without postback). So, when the button is clicked, the javascript function `sendHiddenValueToServer()` is called, making an Ajax request to the Page Method, passing the Hidden Field Value as Parameter.

First, you will need a `ScriptManager` declared with the EnablePageMethods property set to true:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

I tested using the following markup:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="External.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <button id="button1" onclick="sendHiddenValueToServer();">
        Send Value to Server</button>
    </div>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

In the Javascript file:

```
function populateHidden() {
    document.getElementById('Hidden2').value = "dsadsadas";
}

function sendHiddenValueToServer() {
    PageMethods.ReceiveHiddenValue(
            document.getElementById('Hidden2').value,
            function () { alert("success!") },
            function () { alert("error!") });
}
```

And in the codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "register", "populateHidden();", True)
    End If
End Sub

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Sub ReceiveHiddenValue(ByVal value As String)        
    Dim str As String = value
    ' Save Value to database
End Sub
```

Comment: what if I wanted to use the markup in a regular `.html` page instead of the  `.aspx` page? Will the solution you provided work? And if yes, how can I edit it? While considering the asp.net server controls, changing them might cause a problem ?

Comment: You can perfectly use a regular `.html` page, but you'll have to use jQuery (or other JS framework) to make the Ajax requests.

Comment: SO to make things clearer, I have a regular .html page where I have an html <input type="hidden" ID="Hidden2"/> and I call External.js. In turn, External.js should assign a value to Hidden2 and then pass its value to the code-behind in order to store it in a database. Is the way to go for jQuery? I can't do that using javascript? The problem I am facing is the <asp:ScriptManager> as it doesn't work in plain html. Would really appreciate if you could give me some keywords to look for and research.

Comment: You can make the Ajax request with raw Javascript, but will be like  reinventing the wheel. Another solution, could be use jQuery to call a WebService (.asmx) or Generic Handler (.ashx), both build on top of ASP.Net engine. Take a look at [this](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) and [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/104/Many-ways-to-communicate-with-your-database-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASP.NET) articles.

Comment: Managed to make an Ajax Request from raw javascript to a WebMethod in my code behind and I will post the code in answer. However, when I want to call the `populateHidden()` method on `Page_Load` event, I think I cannot use `scriptManager` because it is an `asp server Control` and I do not think it will work with plain html. Therefore, I would appreciate your advice on whether there is a way that I can still call the external `populateHidden();` method using an alternative such as `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`  this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx